# SPA with RESTful backend

Tags: web-applications, rest, angularjs

I'm building an app based on ng-seed which is angular setup with routing out of the box. I'm backing the app with a rest interface of which I aim for Richardson level 3 compliance.

Often it seems like there is some tension between the two. Lets say the api exposes some resources with links to other parts of the api. Say a object with rel and href pointing to /api/stuff/id . The app has a frontend for stuff so we wish to take the user to /app/#/stuff/id but then the app needs to know how routing in the api is setup in every detail to be able to parse the href pointing to the api.

I'm thinking maybe the routing is the problem and it would be better if the app made the request first to /api/stuff/id which would return the raw id and then the app didn't have to parse anything and then the app would update the location after the logic had executed.

Or maybe I should just bite the bullet and parse the api route.

Comment: `I'm thinking maybe the routing is the problem and it would be better if the app made the request first to /api/stuff/id which would return the raw id and then the app didn't have to parse anything and then the app would update the location after the logic had executed` -- Seems like a sensible approach.

Comment: Also related: [How useful/important is REST HATEOS (maturity level 3}?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335967)